# How to use .replaceWith to rewrite HTML based on page width, without refresh?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, replacewith

I'm attempting to replace certain blocks of HTML markup with different blocks of HTML based on the browser's width. I have a working model - See the heading: "ACME Health Plans".

[codepen](http://codepen.io/v_for_vinsanity/pen/mWGRyw)

Currently, I'm using:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
    var size = $(window).width();
    $('h4.title1').replaceWith('<h4 class="panel-title"><a role="button" class="footer-heads" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" data-href-mobile="#collapseOne" data-href-desktop="https://www.google.com/"><strong>ACME Health Plans</strong></a></h4>');
    $('.footer-collapse').addClass('panel-collapse collapse');
    $('.footer-heads').addClass('collapsed');
  } else {
    $('h4.title1').replaceWith('<h4 class="panel-title"><strong>ACME Health Plans</strong></h4>');
    $('.footer-collapse').removeClass('panel-collapse collapse');
    $('.footer-heads').removeClass('collapsed');
  }
});
```

The goal is to use `.replaceWith` to swap out the HTML, but in order for it to take effect I need to refresh the page. Is there a way around this and/or is there a better way to achieve this outcome without needing to refresh the page?

Comment: This looks like it is better achieved using CSS Media Queries: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

You can call your function following each window resize event:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $(window).resize(resizeHtml);
  function resizeHtml(){
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
      var size = $(window).width();
      $('h4.title1').replaceWith('<h4 class="panel-title"><a role="button" class="footer-heads" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" data-href-mobile="#collapseOne" data-href-desktop="https://www.google.com/"><strong>ACME Health Plans</strong></a></h4>');
      $('.footer-collapse').addClass('panel-collapse collapse');
      $('.footer-heads').addClass('collapsed');
    } else {
      $('h4.title1').replaceWith('<h4 class="panel-title"><strong>ACME Health Plans</strong></h4>');
      $('.footer-collapse').removeClass('panel-collapse collapse');
      $('.footer-heads').removeClass('collapsed');
    }
  }
});
```

Other ways to assign a function to the resize event would be:

```
window.onresize = resizeHtml;
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHtml);
```

Note that there are performance concerns when attaching functions to the window resize event and if you're doing a lot of processing, throttling the events may be the way to go: https://gomakethings.com/javascript-resize-performance/

Comment: Thanks c-bro, I appreciate the answer!

Comment: It may be worth you looking into throttling, no need to run the entire function for every pixel the window is resized